# Ubuntu Adding items to /etc/rc.local

Tags: linux

When I add items to /etc/rc.local do I need to add them above Exit 0? Or once I add an item do I need to remove Exit 0?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You add them above `exit 0`. Don't remove it.